# Unmarshal custom types with jsonpb

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

What's the best way to convert this json object to protobuf?

JSON:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "_list": {
    "some1": { "value": 1 },
    "some2": [
      { "value": 2 },
      { "value": 3 },
    ]
  }
}
```

Proto:

```
message Something {
     string name = 1;
     message ListType {
       repeated string = 1;
     }
     map<string, ListType> _list = 2;
   }
```

Without having the `_list` in the message I would use jsonpb.Unmarsal, but I can't think of a way to define the Unmarshaler interface on a type that is generated in a diff package.

I also thought of having `_list` as a Any (json.RawMessage) and handle it after the Unmarshal (but can't make this to work; err message: `Any JSON doesn't have '@type'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With _list being inconsistent (not just a list of strings/map of values/etc) and you mentioning you looked into using Any you could consider making your message:

`message Something {
     string name = 1;
     google.protobuf.Struct _list = 2;
}`

https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/ptypes/struct/struct.proto

With that you can marshal/unmarshal json to/from proto messages using [github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb) which is actually designed for use with the grpc gateway but you can use it too

Comment: Any code sample on how to converta json string to proto struct type using `jsobpb` would be helpful.